# Clone(); in jquery appends 8 times instead of one

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using clone(); to append static HTML code to a div. But it appends it 8 times for some reason instead of one. What could be the possible issue with that?

```
    $('#irbis').click(function(){
                                    $('#irbiswindow').fadeIn(function(){
                                        $('#irbiswindow').append( $("#tableToClone").clone());
    
    }); 
    });
```

and html part:

```
    <div id="irbiswindow" class="mainscreen"></div>
    
                    <div style="display:none">
                        <table id="tableToClone" class="ts">
                            <tr>
                                <th class="ts-yw4l" rowspan="3">
                                    <img src="img/...jpg" class="previewing">
                                    <img src="img/...jpg" class="previewing">
                                    <img src="img/...jpg" class="previewing">
                                    <img src="img/...jpg" class="previewing">
                                    <img src="img/....jpg" class="previewing">
                                </th>
                                <th class="ts-yw4l">
                                    <p class="comment">Rare and gorgeous "irbis" snow leopards observe the surroundings ready to hunt.</p>
                                    <p class="comment">3Ds Max, Photoshop, Vray, Zbrush</p>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="ts-yw4l"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="ts-yw4l"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

As the result, I get 8 "tableToClone" tables inside an "irbiswindow" div...

Comment: Show where you are adding the click handler. It sounds like it is inside a loop that runs 8 times and you are adding the same handler 8 times. Or the same script is being loaded 8 times

Comment: https://github.com/stmalk/stmalk.github.io/blob/master/port/index.js   here it is in the very end. It runs on click event so it can't be in the loop

Comment: put relevant code in question itself. That repo is likely to change over time and questions should be self contained

Comment: That's what I did initially.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I used html instead of append and it removed 8 clones.